# Gem::LoadError: Rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run `rake db:migrate` locally but I'm getting the below error:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.1. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

Not sure why this is happening? It came out of no where.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can delete your `Gemfile.lock`. Then run `bundle install` and bundler will recreate updated `Gemfile.lock` with correct rake.

I just did that and this worked for me.

Comment: You need to use this method with care, since it may change the versions of other dependencies in your project. Usually it's not a problem, but you should be aware that it might bring incompatibilities or regressions

Comment: That's the reason to write versions to Gemfile. The same problem happens when deploying somewhere else.

Comment: When I delete it, it automatically creates itself again in less than a second

Answer (score 4):

Do as it says. Call rake as

```
bundle exec rake
```

Or, alterantively, run bundler like this:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

And then:

```
bin/rake
```

This is happening because there're different versions of `rake` installed on your system, and it is loading the wrong one by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and see if that works for you.

You seem to have multiple versions of `rake` installed. Do `gem list` to identify if that is the case.

Depending on that, you may want to uninstall one version using `gem uninstall rake`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me but I found a fix. In the application folder you are making (where you find app bin ect..) Open your "Gemfile.lock" find "rake 10.1.1"(just use find or search), change it to 10.2.2, save then rake. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think that updating all Gemfile.lock is dangerous, especially when you have many gems without a specific versions. Sometimes when you update a gem some behaviour is changed and it is really annoying to find why it happened.

For myself, I had the same problem and the solution was to modify Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', "~> 10.2.2"
```

to

```
gem 'rake', "~> 11.1.2"
```

and then run

```
bundle update rake
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't/don't specify `gem 'rake'` in my Gemfile, so I simply ran `bundle update rake` which correctly updated Gemfile.lock.