# Rails migration error when running migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I do `rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.0. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

How can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that some applications may specify different versions of gems than the ones you have installed.

Try using `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Using `bundle exec` guarantees that the program is run with the environment specified in the gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be other gems in the Gemfile which are dependent on rake 10.2.2, while you are trying to install rake 10.1.0 via your gemfile or explicitly mentioned it.  A look into your Gemfile will help.

In case you have specific environment, you may want to run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

to make sure you are running it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As per [another answer given on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23003034/443986), you can also try deleting the Gemfile.lock file and re-running `bundle install` to regenerate the Gem dependencies.